# Make a movie of trajectories in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, movie, differential-equations

I want to create a movie in MATLAB which looks like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8z_tSVeEFTA

Mathematically, I have the differential equations and the code to solve them numerically:

```
% lorenz - Program to compute the trajectories of the Lorenz
% equations using the adaptive Runge-Kutta method.
clear;  help lorenz;

%* Set initial state x,y,z and parameters r,sigma,b
state = input('Enter the initial position [x y z]: ');
r = input('Enter the parameter r: '); 
sigma = 10.;   % Parameter sigma
b = 8./3.;     % Parameter b
param = [r sigma b];  % Vector of parameters passed to rka
tau = 1;       % Initial guess for the timestep
err = 1.e-3;   % Error tolerance

%* Loop over the desired number of steps
time = 0;
nstep = input('Enter number of steps: ');
for istep=1:nstep

%* Record values for plotting
x = state(1); y = state(2); z = state(3);
tplot(istep) = time;  tauplot(istep) = tau;       
xplot(istep) = x;  yplot(istep) = y;  zplot(istep) = z;
if( rem(istep,50) < 1 )
fprintf('Finished %g steps out of %g\n',istep,nstep);
end

%* Find new state using adaptive Runge-Kutta
[state, time, tau] = rka(state,time,tau,err,'lorzrk',param);

end

%* Print max and min time step returned by rka
fprintf('Adaptive time step: Max = %g,  Min = %g \n', ...
       max(tauplot(2:nstep)), min(tauplot(2:nstep)));

      %* Graph the time series x(t)
      figure(1); clf;        % Clear figure 1 window and bring forward
      plot(tplot,xplot,'-')
     xlabel('Time');  ylabel('x(t)')
 title('Lorenz model time series')
 pause(1)  % Pause 1 second

%* Graph the x,y,z phase space trajectory
figure(2); clf;  % Clear figure 2 window and bring forward
% Mark the location of the three steady states
x_ss(1) = 0;              y_ss(1) = 0;       z_ss(1) = 0;
x_ss(2) = sqrt(b*(r-1));  y_ss(2) = x_ss(2); z_ss(2) = r-1;
x_ss(3) = -sqrt(b*(r-1)); y_ss(3) = x_ss(3); z_ss(3) = r-1;
plot3(xplot,yplot,zplot,'-',x_ss,y_ss,z_ss,'*')
view([30 20]);  % Rotate to get a better view 
grid;           % Add a grid to aid perspective
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
title('Lorenz model phase space');
```

But I don't know how to plot two different trajectories at once in different colors, and make a clip that looks like this (with the side plot that shows the X coordinate solutions in the same time).

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Make a for loop, where in each iteration, you create the plot of one frame, and use [`getframe`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to save the current plot. Finally you have an array of images and can save that as video. If you can edit your answer and include the code to create one such trajectory plot, I can post an answer which shows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you, I added the code. But I don't know how to plot two trajectories at once in different colors and on the same time plot x(t) which moves like in the clip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, you already have a for loop, which goes through all time steps. Now, to generate such an animation, we'll want to plot the figure at each time step. This is done by

```
for istep=1:nstep

    %* Record values for plotting
    x = state(1); y = state(2); z = state(3);
    tplot(istep) = time;  tauplot(istep) = tau;       
    xplot(istep) = x;  yplot(istep) = y;  zplot(istep) = z;

    %* Find new state using adaptive Runge-Kutta
    [state, time, tau] = rka(state,time,tau,err,'lorzrk',param);

    %* Create Plot
    figure(2);
    x_ss(1) = 0;              y_ss(1) = 0;       z_ss(1) = 0;
    x_ss(2) = sqrt(b*(r-1));  y_ss(2) = x_ss(2); z_ss(2) = r-1;
    x_ss(3) = -sqrt(b*(r-1)); y_ss(3) = x_ss(3); z_ss(3) = r-1;
    plot3(xplot,yplot,zplot,'-',x_ss,y_ss,z_ss,'*')
    view([30 20]);  % Rotate to get a better view 
    grid;           % Add a grid to aid perspective
    xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
    title('Lorenz model phase space');

    %* Save frame
    output_video(istep) = getframe;

end
```

This will create an array of structs `output_video`, which is of size `1 x nstep` and contains `cdata` (the image data) and `colormap` for each frame.

You can view this video in MATLAB with

```
implay(output_video)
```

or save it do disk using the [`VideoWriter`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) class:

```
v = VideoWriter('my_trajectory_video.avi')
open(v)
writeVideo(v,output_video)
close(v)
```

[image: Result as GIF]

Comment: As a general aside, it's usually at least a little faster to update the `XData`, `YData`, and `ZData` properties (where appropriate) of the `lineseries` object(s) than to make repeated calls to `plot`.

Comment: Yep, you're definitely right. My solution is not really efficient, as the figure is completely recreated in every iteration.